# Android - ListFragment - How to know when the ListView is shown

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have a `ListFragment` in which I need to show an animation once the listview is shown (in other words, when `getView()` is called for the last time in the current sequence of updates.  Is there a callback/listener I can register to notify me that the listview has completed updating other than `getView()`?

It tried overriding both `setListShown()` and `setListShownNoAnimation()` but apparently neither of them get called.

Comment: You probably want `onActivityCreated` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: No, `onActivityCreated()` gets called well before the listview's content has been updated.  The listview is not shown until the content has been updated.  Initially the `ListFragment` just shows a progress indicator. For now, I'm just doing the animation the first time `getView()` is called.